# HTTP requests in Rad Studio Seattle (C++ Builder)

Tags: .net, http, c++-cli, c++builder

Documentation is more than a bit lacking, but I managed to cobble together this bit of code:

```
System::Net::Httpclient::THTTPClient* httpcl=System::Net::Httpclient::THTTPClient::Create();

IHTTPResponse* httpresp=httpcl->Get("http://time.is/");
ShowMessage(httpresp->StatusText);
//ShowMessage(httpresp->ContentAsString(TEncoding::Default));

httpcl->Free();
```

When I run it I just get an error message saying

> Error querying headers: (6) The handle is invalid

I'd just use Indy components if I could figure out how to add them to the IDE.

Comment: Sounds like a typical case of an improperly configured anti-virus / firewall. Ideally, combined with Windows XP anti-malware protection.

Comment: Outbound connections are allowed by default. No third-party anti-virus is installed. The PC is running Windows 10